# Tris vs quads in substance painter

Tags: texturing, topology

I've downloaded Substance painter a couple days ago. Online i've read that is better to triangulate your model before exporting it to substance painter and this has confused me a lot. What's the point of retopo in quads when dynotopo aready works with tris? And if I'm goingo to animate a subject and so that I'll need a good edge flow won't trianguating break this?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good quad edge flow and then triangulate it, it won't break its  quality to animate it.

I think internally all game engines triangulate the model anyways.

That being sad. I used Substance painter sporadically and did not triangulate the mesh before. It works fine.

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what i needed. Two more question: do i have to triangulate before or after the uv unwraping? And in case I don't want to animante my mesh do i still have to retopologize it?

Comment: The graphic card needs the mesh triangulated so all engines do triangulate the meshes. The problem with not triangulating is that if your engine chooses to triangulate the mesh in a different way then substance painter the normals can get a bit wonky. I would recommend doing the triangulation before texturing. Especially if you have glossy smooth surfaces.

Comment: @gigggig96 You should triangulate after uv unwrapping. You do not necessarily need to retopologize it if you do not want to animate it. You can see Meshes on Sketchfab that have millions of polys and still are fast to rotate around, zoom in on etc. If it is a static object for a game it would make sense to retopo it though. Also unretopoed meshes might be harder to UV unwrap by hand.